# how to repetitively spawn a SKnode while a button is active

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, touch, game-physics

I'm creating a game and I am trying to create a shooting method. i have the bullets spawning at a gun and moving in the direction f a joystick. here is how i am spawning bullets at a consistent rate (a fire rate) with the gun and moving in the direction toward the joystick.

```
 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

if fireWeapon == true {
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.25, target: self, 
     selector: Selector ("spawnBullet1"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
func spawnBullet1(){

    self.addChild(bullet1)

    bullet1.position = CGPoint (x: hero.position.x , y:hero.position.y) 
    bullet1.xScale = 0.5
    bullet1.yScale = 0.5
    bullet1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bullet1.size)
    bullet1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bullet1
    bullet1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.enemy1
    bullet1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    bullet1.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
}
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent  
event:UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        let node = nodeAtPoint(location)
if (CGRectContainsPoint(joystick.frame, location)) {

            stickActive = true
if stickActive == true {

            fireWeapon = true

            }
```

This method only launches the first bullet then right before it launches the second one the app crashes. everything with the bullet movement is perfect just spawning a stream of bullets for firing. I can't think of an alternative way to create a fire speed.

Comment: What is the error message you get when it crashes?

Comment: Also, what is the bullet1 variable?

Comment: it says, something like. error crash, attempt to add SkSpritenode which already has a parent" which usually is what happens when you call the same self.addchild twice @mate Hegedus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always trying to add the same child when you call `self.addChild(bullet1)`

You need to **create a new instance every time** in the `spawnBullet1` function and add that object as a child.

Comment: could you be more specific? could you give me an example? @mate Hegedus

Comment: what do you mean button 1? basically i have two bool values weapon fire and stick active. stick at vie becomes true once you touch the joystick. once stick active is true weapon fire = true which starts a NStimer in my override view did began method which loops my bullet spawning method spawnBullet1() @mate Hegedus

Comment: @gkolman in the spawnBullet1() function you have a variable called bullet1. You are using it at self.addChild(bullet1) show me how this bullet1 gets created. Because you need to create a new instance in this function. You cannot use the same one. Because essentially what you are doing is you're trying to add the same bullet over and over again.

Comment: My code I provided is all i have, i guess that where i am going wrong lol. Could you provide me with an example of an instance that would create bullet 1 instead of repetitively adding one? @Mate Hegedus

Comment: i have also tried a run block method that did not work and caused th same error @MateHegedus

Comment: No you didn't provided all that you have, because if it was really the case then your code is incomplete, not compilable and then unable to generate any crash. So, please provide more or don't hope to have more information...

Comment: what additional code are you asking for ? my project is pretty big and i didn't want to annoy people with 100+ lines of code and saying figure it out @Jean-BaptisteYunès